# Not even .. could cope with .. VS Even ... could not cope with

Tags: sentence-structure

There is a sentence where the **not** is put ahead:

> Not even a 20-year-old could cope with the chairman’s jam-packed schedule.

Why not express it as:

> Even a 20-year-old couldn't cope with the chairman’s jam-packed schedule.

Why put the **not** ahead?

Comment: It could perfectly well be expressed in either way. Putting _not_ at the beginning simply adds extra emphasis to it.

Comment: @KateBunting Since I'm not British, I fell this expression a bit odd, but it actually not.